# Use of CNTLM with out a password

Tags: passwords, cntlm

I need to know, if possible use the CNTLM connection 
but with out using a password.

I ask this cause in my company we use a SMART CARD pin 
so we have no password.

Comment: AFAIK, NTLM doesn't support smart cards, only Kerberos does, so...

Comment: Thanks Grawity... do you know please a soft that can be used togetter with putty and can auth via Kerberos please ? Thanks again. Denis.

Comment: Or maybe can be that we use Kerberos at log in time and then we use NTLM in order to go out in internet and NTLM take some hide pass from Kerberos login ?